# How to insert a circumflex symbol (^)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I would like to insert a circumflex on a letter as in latex `\hat{X}` in Adobe Illustrator.

I searched so many web pages but I couldn't find a quite decent solution.

Comment: Which layout (language) does your keyboard have? I can just hit the ^-key on my keyboard followed by the letter to add the hat. It only works if the font contains that symbol - can't be used on any letter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However the "^" symbol should be placed at the top of the letter X.

Comment: Also, what OS? On Mac [UK Eng] it's opt/i then space [or option/i + any letter that can take a circumflex accent] eg ^ â ê î ô û

Comment: To add it to any letter, such as X̂, you need the combining diacritical, which is U+0302 - method again will depend on OS

Comment: I am using Windows OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there's no way in Illustrator unless you have installed the language where it's used. Copy/pasting the symbol from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X%CC%82) the result is a simple *X*.

This image is the character X with -450 pt tracking followed by the circumflex, same size as the X, with these character parameters:

[image]

Making two character styles can accelerate the process:

[image]

**Insert after the comments:**

This is the *special character* copy/paste result from Wikipedia to InDesign in Arial, Helvetica, Times and Avenir fonts:

[image]

The same in Illustrator:

[image]

Comment: Is there no way to do combining diacriticals on Windows? I can copy/paste the wikipedia letter to here & it works X̂ - it's built of 2 elements, X and the combiner  ̂, which does its own tracking shift.

Comment: I'm a Mac user, maybe that's the difference, I will try with other fonts or applications

Comment: I'm Mac too, copy/paste works, as does typing X then just digging out the right diacritical from the character viewer & double-clicking it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you trying in Illustrator? I updated the answer with my attempts

Comment: I don't have Illustrator; hmmm...I can do it anywhere else, but not in anything Adobe :\

Comment: @Tetsujin There is a way to do combining diacritics in Windows 10.  I have a UK English Extended keyboard selected, and typing AltGr+6 (which is the circumflex symbol) followed by the letter of your choice results in a circumflex above a letter, but only if the glyph already exists in the font. The problem is I don't know any fonts which have an X with a circumflex.

Comment: @BillyKerr - On Mac it appears that the OS can combine any letter with a diacritical, simply if it's a letter that generally takes one, like an accented vowel, or by hammering at it with the Keyboard Viewer if it doesn't. Adobe, however, appear to have their own way of [not] handling it, unfortunately. I think I derailed Daniello's answer a bit by failing to recognise that earlier :\

Comment: @Tesujin this is weird, I found out I can get a circumflex over an X in LibreOffice with the combining circumflex, but not in Illustrator. Looks like you're right, it would seem the problem is with Illustrator, not the operating system.